# "Method 'Rows' of object '_Global' failed " when called second time from

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project that I've been working that takes a mainframe generated report and parses it, pulling additional information from the mainframe and generating a capacity vs load report.  When it is run the first time through by loading the report everything works just fine.  It creates a new workbook, names it, saves it, everything.  I am trying to add the ability to add an item to report without having to modify the mainframe report and re-parse the entire thing.  I am calling the exact same subs and functions, however when attempting to add an item to the report and it gets to this line in the code it fails.

```
Set xlcell = WB.Sheets(WCSheetName).Cells(WB.Sheets(WCSheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B")
```

This code is in a function which is called from the same sub in both instances.  the function is defined as

```
Function AddToWC(ByVal WCSheetName As String, _
            ByVal WCName As String, _
            ByVal Cmpt As String, _
            ByVal Parent As String, _
            ByVal dDate As Date, _
            ByVal ReqHrs As Single, _
            ByVal WB As Workbook, _
            ByVal ID As String, _
            ByVal Seq As String, _
            ByVal Description As String, _
            ByVal Plt As String, _
            ByVal Que As Long) As Date
```

As best I can tell, this should work as I've qualified both the workbook and the worksheet that it is supposed to be referencing

the function is called using this line of code

```
CDT = AddToWC("WC_Summary", rs!WCID, gProdStruct.Components(Y).Name, gProdStruct.Name, CDT, xlCell.Offset(0, 16).value - xlCell.Offset(0, 11).value, CPWB, RefID, rs!SeqNum, rs!OpDesc, rs!WCPlt, xlCell.Offset(0, 11).value)
```

the workbook is verified and passed as `CPWB` and is set to the correct workbook by first checking to see if the workbook is already open by calling `gCheckForWorkbook Plt, IsPList` and then assigning it to `CPWB` using this line `Set CPWB = Application.Workbooks(gWBName)`

this runs this sub and sets a global variable

```
Sub gCheckForWorkbook(ByVal Plt As String, Optional ByVal IsPList As Boolean)
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WBE As Boolean
        For Each WB In Workbooks
            If InStr(1, WB.Name, "Capacity Planning Rep", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                If IsPList = False Then
                    If MsgBox("A Capacity Planning workbook is already open." & vbCrLf & "Would You Like To Use It?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                        gWBName = WB.Name
                        WBE = True
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        MsgBox "Please Close The Open Workbook And Run The Report Again"
                        ' return value to exit sub
                        WBE = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Else
                    WBE = True
                End If
            End If
        Next WB
        If WBE = False Then gCreateWorkBook Plt
End Sub
```

Comment: Please try with `Set xlcell = Nothing` just before the failing line `Set xlcell = WB.Sheets("......`.

Comment: @Ralph - that seems to have done the trick.  Can you please explain why it would work?

Comment: @Ralph nope, it worked once but back to the same problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that for what ever reason this section of the line of code `.Cells(Rows.Count, "B")` is the exact portion that was causing my problem. It seems the Rows.Count was still considered unqualified and when i changed it from

```
Set xlcell =WB.Sheets(WCSheetName).Cells(WB.Sheets(WCSheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B")
```

to

```
Set xlcell = WB.Sheets(WCSheetName).Cells(WB.Sheets(WCSheetName).Cells(​WB.Sheets(WCSheetNam‌​e).Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B")
```

it works perfectly